# Windows Authentication and add Authorization Roles through database - MVC asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to mvc4 asp .net and confused with the authentication and authorization. Our's is an internal website that takes username(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name) from windows authentication and check against database if the username exists and what roles the user has. I want to use the global [Authorize] attribute and roles,  to give access to controllers. Can anyone help me on how to start with.

For now, I have a function that passes username and get the user data and related roles from database, the query data is added to the model.So, I am using this function to give access to the website but I want to use the same data to check against all controllers and views without querying against db all the time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You just need to [create a custom role provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx). You do this by creating a class that inherits from `System.Web.Security.RoleProvider` and overriding certain members. The below code should get you started. Replace all the `throw new NotImplementedException()` stuff with your implementation of the function. For example, `IsUserInRole` you would provide code that would query your database to see if the user is in the specified role.

```
using System.Web.Security;

namespace MyNamespace
{        
    public class MyRoleProvider : RoleProvider
    {
        public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string ApplicationName
        {
           get; set;
        }

        public override void CreateRole(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwOnPopulatedRole)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] FindUsersInRole(string roleName, string usernameToMatch)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] GetAllRoles()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] GetUsersInRole(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void RemoveUsersFromRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool RoleExists(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

You may not need to implement all of it. For example, if your application won't be creating or deleting Roles, then no need to do anything with `CreateRole` or `DeleteRole`.

You also need to register your role provider with ASP.NET framework so it knows to make use of it. Update your `web.config` like below.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <roleManager defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider" enabled="true">
            <providers>
                <add
                    name="MyRoleProvider"
                    type="MyNamespace.MyRoleProvider"           
                    applicationName="MyApplicationName" />
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you so much .. I will start with this and let you know if I have any questions

Comment: can you please tell me how do I call this... like [Authorize (what to call here to check Roles)]

Comment: @GiGi Assuming you've implemented the role manager as I described, then you could do something like `[Authorize(Roles="Administrators")]` on an action method in your controller, which would restrict it so that only users in the "Administrators" could access that action method. See [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: I got this error , so I am checking how to fix it .." It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. "

Comment: @GiGi That seems unrelated. Make sure you configured the directory that contains the web.config as an application. See [this](http://forums.iis.net/t/1148147.aspx?It+is+an+error+to+use+a+section+registered+as+allowDefinition+MachineToApplication+beyond+application+level+).

Comment: Yes it seems unrelated, I got the error after I added <roleManager >

Comment: @GiGi Did you add it in the web.config at the root of your application?

Comment: Hey Guys make sure you "enable" the role manager feature. If you get the Role Manager Feature is not enabled then you have to put enabled="true" on your rolemanager node of your web.config file. 
    <roleManager defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider" enabled="true">

Comment: @DevinPrejean thank you so much. I was pulling my hair out trying to get this to work.