# How to use Roles with Integrated Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, windows-authentication

I'm working on a Web Application implemented in ASP.NET MVC 5 with Web API 2.

I've implemented Integrated Windows Authentication by adding the following code to web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <authentication>
      <windowsAuthentication enabled="true"/>
    </authentication>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

and by adding `[Authorize]` annotation on top of my controllers.

Now, I'm asked to give access to some functionality based on the user's role. I've got a table where I hold the user permissions, but I don't know how I can create those roles, and associate the right permissions with them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

[UPDATE]

Based on mason's answer, I've updated the code a bit.

Added the following line to web.config:

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add
        name="MyRoleProvider"
        type="MyApp.App_Start.MyRoleProvider"
        applicationName="My Tool" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

MyRoleProvider.cs:

```
public class MyRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    private MyEntities db = new MyEntities();

    public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override string ApplicationName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override void CreateRole(string roleName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwOnPopulatedRole)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override string[] FindUsersInRole(string roleName, string usernameToMatch)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override string[] GetAllRoles()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override string[] GetUsersInRole(string roleName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void RemoveUsersFromRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    {
        vUser user = db.vUsers.Where(u => u.UserName == username).First();
        if (roleName == "User")
        {
            if (user.IsAllowedToView == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (roleName == "Administrator")
        {
            if (user.IsAllowedToSubmit == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override bool RoleExists(string roleName)
    {
        if (roleName == "User" || roleName == "Administrator")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

When I use `[Authorize]` annotation on my controllers, and call `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` it returns the ID that I use to login to my machine. (Part of AD) But, if I use [Authorize(Roles="User")], it keeps asking for my username and password again and again, and doesn't accept anything. I put breakpoints to every single method on MyRoleProvider class, but the program hasn't stopped at any which makes me think maybe it is not even calling the provider.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32590333/1139830). You just need to inherit a class, wire up the methods to pull the appropriate data from your table, and then you can begin using those roles in your application.

Comment: @mason Thanks for directing me to that post. I've implemented the role manager, and added to my web.config. My question now is how am I going to pass the user id to the role manager. I have `[Authorize(Roles="User")]` on top of a controller, but it doesn't let me view it. How do I pass the username parameter to public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName) ?

Comment: You don't need to. When we registered the our role manager in the web.config like I showed in my answer, the system becomes aware of it. If you were to take a look at the source code for that `Authorize` attribute, you'd see that it's calling into the registered role manager (set a breakpoint in your role manager if you want to verify) on your behalf. So there's no need for you to manually get the username and pass it to the role manager. But if you ever do need the username for some other reason, that comes from `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`.

Comment: @mason Thanks for the response. When I print HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, I can see my user id, but when I use `[Authorize(Roles="User")]` annotation, it keeps asking my username and password, and it doesn't accept the username and password I use to login to Windows. I also put some breakpoints to the MyRoleProvider class, but looks like it is not even being called. I've only implemented IsUserInRole() and RoleExists() methods. Do I need to implement some other ones for it to work?

Comment: You'd be able to tell by setting breakpoints in the other methods in the role manager and seeing if they get hit. But if you copied my code directly, then you should get `NotImplementedException` when those are hit. So that leads me to think it's not even reaching the role manager. Update your question showing how you registered your role manager in your web.config, and also show your role manager code. Is this website hosted on a server that's part of Active Directory, the same one that your client PC is located on?

Comment: @mason updated the question, and added the code pieces you've requested. I really appreciate the help. Website is hosted on my local machine, and my machine is on domain.

Comment: I think your permission and role concepts are clashing. You shouldn't grant permissions to users (ex: `user.IsAllowedToSubmit`). Instead, your site should define whether a role is allowed to perform a specific action (such as via applying the Authorize attribute to an action method). Then you just have to check if that user has that role. So `IsUserInRole` should return true if the user is in the role `roleName`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91115/discussion-between-jail-and-mason).

Answer (score 0):

Over each controller or Even each method inside the controller you can add your own custom authorization role.

```
    [Authorize(Roles="Admin,Doctor")]
    public class Investigation : Controller
    {

    }
```

NOTE:
The roles must be written the same way it was inserted in the database.(Case senstive)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to manage the roles from Active Directory you could always create Active Directory user groups for each particular role then use the `[Authorize(Roles="{AD_GROUP_NAME}")]` annotation on top of your controller.

Comment: This requires you to be a domain administrator, or to have a domain administrator's cooperation. While it applies to some situations, it definitely doesn't apply to all, and specifically doesn't apply to this situation because he already has a database with that information.

Comment: Agreed. Just offering a possible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific situation (based on chat), it sounds like a role based concept is not appropriate for you, since your permissions are stored at the user level instead of the role level, and you're not allowed to change how that works due to company restrictions.

Instead, you should [write your own filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx) that you can apply to your action methods. That filter should probably implement [IAuthorizationFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iauthorizationfilter(v=vs.118).aspx).  That would allow you to do something like:

```
[RequirePermissions("Save")]
public ActionResult Save(Data date)
{
    Database.Save(data);
    return View("Success");
}
```

And probably the logic of verifying the user has that permission should be abstracted out to a common class so that you can also reuse the logic in views.

Answer (score 0):

```
        public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {
            var userrole = from role in db.roles
                           where username == role.userID
                           select role.role1;
            if (userrole != null)
                return userrole.ToArray();
            else
                return new string[] { };
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

this function should be edited.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: I edit this function in MyRoleProvider.cs and then it works! I don't need to input my username and password anymore when it runs:)