# Active Directory Authentication with Identity Role Authorization

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I need some help to start a MVC project.

Is there any way to authenticate an Active Directory user on an intranet MVC page using Windows Identity tables to manage role authorization?

Any guide would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is too broad, please show what you've tried and any code you have to illustrate a specific issue that you need help with.  Asking for general guidance is difficult if we don't know what you've tried and what you're specifically having trouble with. Questions should show some effort towards actually solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand the problem right but ASP MVC and IIS supports windows domain authentication with NTLM or Kerberos options.
So you can login to your intranet website using your domain account.

Refer this topic:
[Windows Authentication for ASP.NET MVC 4 - how it works, how to test it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224174/windows-authentication-for-asp-net-mvc-4-how-it-works-how-to-test-it)

Comment: My doubt, once authenticated against the domain it is possible to manage the roles through a database, as do the projects with individual user accounts?

Comment: @labdev now I got your problem.
Please, take a look on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888418/how-to-use-roles-with-integrated-windows-authentication