# Create User Roles In Asp.net Web Application project

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, web, authorization

I need guidance from all of you experts for a simple task.
i'm working on my final year project which is a web based application. 
In this application i have to create several users which will do different taks for example accountant will manage fee and admin will manage teacher and student accounts and so on. 
i'm working hard on this and I've learned simple authentication. 
I'm able to authorize users based on their user names and allow them to access specific pages or specific folder having multiple pages. 
I'm doing this by using form authentication.
but
now as i want to create user role and assign different roles to different users so that I don't have to add each and every user name in web config file.
please suggest me the easiest way to do this. is there any book, or article or youtube video from where i can learn it ? 
I've searched stack overflow and msdn but i'm unable to understand. 
I'm waiting for your suggestions,
thanks in advance.
I'm nor working in MVC.
I'm using .net 4.5, visual studio 2012 and sql server 2014

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Authentication and add Authorization Roles through database - MVC asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589863/windows-authentication-and-add-authorization-roles-through-database-mvc-asp-ne)

Answer (score 0):

You can attach roles to your user in this way:
in globl.asax add the following event, read the roles to assign to the logged user, create a new GenericPincipal and assign it to the user.

```
    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var app = (HttpApplication) sender;
            var ctx = app.Context;

            if (ctx.User != null)
            {
                //Read the roles from database for current user, create a new Principal, attach the principal to the user (im using EF)               
                using (var context = new BackendDbContext())
                {
                    var user = context.Set<User>().Find(Convert.ToInt32(ctx.User.Identity.Name));
                    var identity = new GenericIdentity(user.UserId.ToString());
                    var principal = new GenericPrincipal(
                        identity,
                        new[] {user.UserRoleId.ToString()});

                    ctx.User = principal;
                }
            }
         }
```

Comment: I have stored my registered user in sql database and this user is loging in to web application by comparing user name and password from user table.... now how i will assign that user a ROLE ?

Comment: just like in the example above: read the role/roles from database for the current user and set the role to the principal

Comment: how to create a role in database ? 
you mean i have to create a table in database with two columns role id and role name and then access to that table ? 
Please can you write a complete procedure for this ?

Comment: It depends, if you have only one role for user you can add a column to the user table otherwise you have to create a relation table between users and roles ( many to may)

Comment: I know i'm wasting your time but i'm struggling with it...
I have more than one roles for example principal, accountant, student, teacher etc and i want to allow them on the basis of their roles, 
how can i manage this , what i should do in the database table, and how can i implement these in web application, please guide me step by step or suggest me an article or video on it .. i'm waiting for your kind reply :)