# Custom Roles and Permissions in ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to add a configurable user permission module in my ASP.NET Webforms application (NOT Using MVC) which can be configured by an admin user. My user database schema looks something like below 
[image]

I want admin users to create Roles (UserGroup), assign rights to a group and create users with group it belongs to. Up to this point is okay I can do it myself but my question is what is best approach to implement the permissions once users are created. To be more specific say I have menu on my master page which contains EntityName and it has View,Add,Edit,Delete sub menus. For example *Customer

- View
- Add
- Edit
- Delete

I want the menu/sub-menu to be enabled/disabled based on the permission of the user who is logged in. I also want it to be restricted for a user who attempts to navigate by directly typing in the url of a page on which he has no permission.

I would like to point that the users(admin) should be able to create a role so no hard-coded role name etc in the web config file.

Edit : - There is an [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589863/windows-authentication-and-add-authorization-roles-through-database-mvc-asp-ne) but this does not answer how to restrict an user trying to navigate to a page by typing url on which he has no access.

Comment: The same question was asked by me using an incorrect id, I deleted that question and asked this using my correct profile. So the question you are referring does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Perform The UI Logic 
        // Assuming That You Are Tracking The User For Each Reqeust In Session["UserID"]
        ShowHideMenuOrSubMenu_Role_Your_RoleName(Session["UserID"].ToString());
    }
    public static void ShowHideMenuOrSubMenu_Role_Your_CRUD_RoleName(string UserID)
    {
        if (CheckUserRole("Your_CRUD_Role", UserID))
        {
            //1. Set Your Front End WebForm Control To Disable
            //2. Set Your Front End WebForm Control CSS 
            // Whichever you prefer . 
        }
    }
    public static bool CheckUserRole(string Role_CRUD , string UserID)
    {

        // Go Into DB/Repository/EF Where Your Role/User Setting Is Set .
        // Perform Checking
        // Assuming The Result Is A Bool Checking Result That You Checked
        return Result;
    }
```

Comment: The proposed code is based on assumption that you are not using the .net Identity , so you might need to query and check each time user request the page ( which is bad - Increase the server load by do extra algorithm ) . Plus its best to factor out the static algorithm and place it somewhere else  and not in the page instance level .