# Windows authentication and roles authentication through stored procedure - mvc asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am new to using ASP.NET MVC 5, and I am trying to authenticate user roles through a stored procedure.  Can anyone offer resources or advice on how to design this sort of architecture?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Authentication and add Authorization Roles through database - MVC asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589863/windows-authentication-and-add-authorization-roles-through-database-mvc-asp-ne)

Comment: StackOverflow demands you to show some code that you tried yourself

Comment: @Technotronic I haven't implement any code yet. So far what I had done. Create mvc app throug visual studio using Windows Authentication and stored procedure that will validate user right.

Comment: Be clear about what you are asking. Users are authenticated but not roles.  "authenticate the user roles" is confusing as roles are NOT authenticated but they do matter in membership or authorization.

Comment: Are you asking about getting the roles that a user has?

Comment: @DaniDev correct. Roles that has been assigned to the users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have done things correctly in Visual Studio, a database schema will have been created for you on (most probably) your **localDB**. You will have to identify that database server and instance and you should see a corresponding table structure for users and roles. Once you have identified the database instance and confirmed the tables have been created and their names match you can create the following stored procedure (the table names may be different).

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE getRolesForUser
    @UserName nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        SELECT        AspNetRoles.Name
        FROM            AspNetRoles 
        INNER JOIN
                        AspNetUserRoles ON AspNetRoles.Id = AspNetUserRoles.RoleId 
        INNER JOIN
                        AspNetUsers ON AspNetUserRoles.UserId = AspNetUsers.Id
        WHERE AspNetUsers.UserName = @UserName 
END
GO
```