# Do you need asp.net identity for windows based intranet AD role authorization?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am building an MVC 5 intranet app that would authenticate via Windows check if a user is in a certain Active Directory group then assign those privileges accordingly depending on what group they are in.

In the past, I have simply got the user and checked if they are in a specified `AD` group then assigned privileges accordingly.

```
public class SomeAuthoriseStuff : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
         return ADMethodToCheckIsInRole.IsInGroup("admins");           
    }
}
```

I don’t really need the membership database that identity creates I simply was thinking of having a user’s table then assign each authenticated user an ID which I can then use to record their details against transactions.
Is this a feasible way to go? Alternatively any other ideas?

Comment: This worked for me in the past: https://tech.trailmax.info/2016/03/using-owin-and-active-directory-to-authenticate-users-in-asp-net-mvc-5-application/

Comment: Cheer I don't need a login screen though

Comment: do you have pass-through authentication in IE? In that case this tutorial is not the right thing for you

Comment: No, you don't need ASP.NET Identity. This can be accomplished without it. You probably don't need custom attributes either. The default `AuthorizeAttribute` should be enough once you've hooked up the proper role provider. I'm not sure if one exists for this (probably it does). But if not, you can implement your [own role provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589863).

Comment: Yes I have pass-through authentication and modified your code trailmax to remove the login part